# What does linsolve(A,B) return when the number of equations is larger then number of variables?

Tags: matlab

I by accident put a matrix A with far more rows then columns into linsolve(A,B). So it should be inconsistent system of equations. However what I got was a 'solution' which fits my task far better. So what exactly does it return when you have more columns then rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have seems to be an **overdetermined linear system**, that can be solved by the least-square method.

If your matrix `A` has more rows than columns (`m > n`) it means that you have *more* equations than unknowns, so an exact solution can be almost impossible to find. What you can obtain is a *good enough* solution that minimizes the error.

You can refer to the page [Overdetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) for more insights.

Comment: To add to this: Its generally better to have an over-determined system, as while you won't get the perfect result, you'll get a better one. Generally the equations appear from aphysycal measurement or modelling of a system where they have some error. The more equations (measurements, models) you put, the less error you will get, as it averages out